# Problem in creating prime generator in python

Tags: python

I tried to make a prime generator in python. Here is what I tried. Can someone please tell me, where am I getting it wrong.

```
for i in range (1, 101):
    if i > 1:
        for x in range (2,i):
            if i % x == 0:
                break
            else:
                print(i)
```

Comment: You can debug printint the variables in each step, so print i before the if, then print x, etc. So you can see in the console what is your coding doing. Keep the good work.

Comment: The PROBLEM is that you cannot conclude that `i` is prime until you get all the way through the `x` list.  If you just unindent those last two lines, so that the `else:` is lines up with the `for x`, then it will accidentally work.  BTW, delete the `if i > 1` line and just start your range with 2 (`range(2,101)`).

Comment: (More hints: you do not need `x` to go all the way to `i`.  You can stop at the square root of `i`.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to test all previous potential factors before being able to identify a prime with this method.

This can translate into:

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    if all(i % x != 0 for x in range (2, i)):
        print(i)
```

Output (flat version for readability):

```
1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

*NB. This is far from an optimal algorithm, you can think of how to improve it by setting a different upper bound for the factors to test.*

I see the hint as been given in the comments, use the square root. You can optimize further by only testing the odd numbers:

```
from math import sqrt, ceil

print(1)
print(2)
for i in range(3, 101, 2):
    if all(i % x != 0 for x in range (2, ceil(sqrt(i)))):
        print(i)
```

Or keep a set of the found primes and only divide by those:

```
print(1)
print(2)
primes = set()
for i in range(3, 101, 2):
    if all(i % x != 0 for x in primes):
        primes.add(i)
        print(i, end=' ')
```

Comment: A minor point, but in your first version, range(2, 1) and range(2, 2) both return an empty iterator.  Since all([]) returns True, the code identifies 1 and 2 as prime.  But mathematically you haven't actually performed the test 1 % 1 == 0 or 2 % 2 == 0.  The second and third versions don't identify 2 as a prime.

Comment: @Paul I was fixing that. 2 was skipped due to the "test odd only" trick. Then you need to hard code 1 and 2 ;)

Comment: You should however never test 1 as a factor ;)